# Change icon notification in different type of situations

Tags: android, notifications, icons

I've set a notification for my Android app, but I have an issue. When my app is running in the background of Android OS, it has different situations that when they happen app notification have to change in the notification bar. For example, you can consider an app like Calendar, Today is 22 July, and I wanna set 22 number icon in notification bar, after that when tomorrow arrives set 23 number icon instead of that and do it way to at the end. how can do it? :)

Comment: You just have to update your Notification providing the same NotificationID. About the number in icon: you have to create a Bitmap and draw it before update the Notification and then set that dynamic icon.

Comment: Do you mean "how to update the notification if my app is in background?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your notification by [submitting a new notification](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationManagerCompat.html#notify(int,%20android.app.Notification)) with the same notification id. So, you just create a new one with the changed icon and call

```
notificationManager.notify(id, notification)
```